# Are Catholic priests allowed by church law to provide professional counseling and referrals to penitents who come to them to confess?

Tags: catholicism, confession, christian-psychology

Let us say we have a priest, who is a licensed psychiatrist as well. A devout Catholic confesses their sins to said priest. The Catholic person chats with the priest, and priest asks follow-up questions like a doctor would. Priest then determines that the person is suffering from a psychological disorder, in this example, depression.

From a professional/moral standpoint the penitent/"patient" should not be obligated to pay the priest for his profession, since they came to confess, not to seek medical help. But as the priest orders penance, is the priest allowed by Church law to disclose to the penitent his diagnosis, offer counseling, and/or suggest to the latter to at least seek another psychiatrist for a second opinion?

Comment: Ooh interesting. Hmm. Other Besides the priest not really staying within his job boundaries here, there are a few things to consider. I may be able to come up with an answer tomorrow, if the resident priest doesn't beat me to it :-)

Comment: Hehe. Counting on your thoughts. Thank you for your interest! :)

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE, and thanks for taking the site tour. Thanks also for asking a question here. I've edited the title to more clearly reflect the question you asked in the body, and to ensure that the question is clearly on-topic here. I hope you get some good answers! Meanwhile, for more on what this site is all about, see: [How we are different than other sites](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites).

Comment: Wow, thank you Lee! My question is clearer now, thanks for editing!

Comment: Ask the Catholic priest Fr. Chad Ripperger, who hold a degree in theology and a PhD in psychology; he is author of the excellent book [_Introduction to the Science of Mental Health_](https://sentrad.org/psychology/), which discusses, _inter alia_, the sacrament of confession. His contact info is [here](https://sentrad.org/).

Comment: I know exactly what is being talked about. I've been talking
To a local priest quite a lot, buy phone, he has helped me with My missing my grandmother, both at Christmas, and recently. I
Have had counseling with him, he has been wonderful, there a few times
He went beyond the call of a pries when it came to helping me. I won't get into details,but he helped me with issues I had that didn't realize I had, He's a fantastic listener, a tops priest, s great advisor, and thanks to him. I know more about the church, and priests than I ever knew. I have
Peppered him with questions, he'd answer me, an

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In essence, care should be taken lest the Sacrament of Confession be confused with psychological counseling. A priest with a degree in psychology should be sure not to confuse the spiritual purpose of the Sacrament with the therapeutic purpose of psychology.

Therefore, the proper procedure would be for the priest to instruct the penitent to bring up his psychological issues outside of Confession. In Confession, what is dealt with is sin and grace (see [*Catechism of the Catholic Church* [CCC] 1422](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ccc_css/archive/catechism/p2s2c2a4.htm)); psychological counseling regards the cognitive and emotive faculties.

Naturally, if the priest is acting in the capacity of a licensed professional psychologist (outside of Confession, obviously), then he may seek remuneration like any other. He may not, of course, charge for Confession. (See [CCC 2121](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ccc_css/archive/catechism/p3s2c1a1.htm#2121).)

(I do not believe there is any official legislation regarding this issue, but I suggest reading the overview on the Sacrament of Penance in [CCC 1422-1470](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ccc_css/archive/catechism/p2s2c2a4.htm); you will see that psychological therapy does not really belong to it.)

Aside from the theological issues, confusing Confession and counseling poses practical issues: for example, a priest can never divulge anything he has learned in Confession for any reason. (See [*Code of Canon Law*, 983](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ENG1104/_P3G.HTM).) Hence, for example, it would be complicated for him (if not impossible) to consult other psychologists, or refer the “patient” to other psychologists.

The proper procedure, then, would be to counsel the penitent to seek psychological counseling (should that be advisable). If the priest is himself a licensed psychologist, he could even suggest that the penitent seek his help outside of confession.

(I think that most priests in this situation, however, would advise the penitent to go to a different therapist or counselor, since it can be complicated to keep track of what has been said under the seal of Confession and what has not.)

Comment: To some extent this answer posits a distinction which doesn't entirely exist in Catholic theology. Yes, Confession and therapy do have different domains, but those domains are  related. The cognitive and emotive faculties do influence whether and how we sin.